# Getting invalid schema error, when having array of mongoose schema objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my schema for userPost.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let userPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id:{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    },
   
    body:{
        type: String
    }

}, {timestamps: true});


const UserPost = mongoose.model("post", userPostSchema);

module.exports = UserPost;
```

Here is my schema for userAccount.js:

```
const userPost = require("./UserPost");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");



let userAccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id:{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    },
    
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    
    posts:
        {
            type: [userPost]
        }
    

}, {timestamps: true});

let userAccount = mongoose.model("account", userAccountSchema);

module.exports = userAccount;
```

I am getting the posts error:

```
node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:984
        throw new TypeError('Invalid schema configuration: ' +
        ^

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `posts`.See http://.../mongoose-schematypes for a list of valid schema types.
    at Schema.interpretAsType (C:\Users\BackEnd\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:984:15)
    at Schema.path (C:\Users\BackEnd\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:677:27)
    at Schema.add (C:\Users\BackEnd\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:495:12)
```

I am having 2 schemas, userPost.js, that I am using in userAccount.js.
What is the problem ?

Why am I getting the following error:

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `posts`

I tried consulting the following link especially the 3rd code excerpt of the official Mongoose's documentation:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays

I changed the following code:

```
posts:[
        {
            type: userPost
        }
    ]
```

To:

```
posts:
{
    type: [userPost]
}
```

but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this can be the case whenever you are referring to other model you always have to use the mongoose reference keyword and then use information from that model to create an array.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your schema as follows:

```
 const userPost = require("./UserPost");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");



let userAccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id:{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    },
    
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    
    posts: [userPost]
        

}, {timestamps: true});

let userAccount = mongoose.model("account", userAccountSchema);

module.exports = userAccount;
```

posts does not need a type declaration.

Comment: node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:984
        throw new TypeError('Invalid schema configuration: ' +
        ^

I got the following error: TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `posts`.See http://..../mongoose-schematypes for a list of valid schema types.

Comment: still getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you have to remember:

1. First is that because you are creating a schema and you are not changing your schema in apps, it is not recommended to use **let**. instead, try to store your schema in a **Const** variable.
2. The "posts" is an array, you can simply write your schema to an array and not use types. Also, you must use the schema on another schema. You can change your code with:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

export const userPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id:{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    },
   
    body:{
        type: String
    }

}, {timestamps: true});


 const UserPost = mongoose.model("post", userPostSchema);

module.exports = UserPost;
```

and then:

```js
import {userPostSchema} from "./UserPost" ;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");



const userAccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id:{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    },
    
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    
    posts: [userPostSchema]
        

}, {timestamps: true});

let userAccount = mongoose.model("account", userAccountSchema);

module.exports = userAccount;
```

Comment: node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:984
        throw new TypeError('Invalid schema configuration: ' +
        ^

I got the following error: TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `posts`.See http://..../mongoose-schematypes for a list of valid schema types.

Comment: These two are the models you are using? nothing more related to mongoose? because I want to develop it for you in sandbox.